# Need to go to a fragment in my mainActivity from a Home Screen Widget?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

Need to go to a `Fragment` in my `MainActivity` from a home screen `Widget`. In my `MainActivity` The first view is a `ListView` in a `Fragment`, there is an add button to enter in some data and this add button opens a `Fragment` that has some `EditText` in it and on save it adds the entered data into the `ListView` back in the main `Fragment` so here's my problem. I can get back to the `MainActivity` by calling

```
Intent details = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
details.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(details);
```

and that gets me back to the main `Fragment` with the `Listview` but how could I get back to the `Fragment` that is called to enter the data on a `Button` click in the `MainActivity`. From the home screen `Widget` I would like to open the enter data Fragment not the main `Fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `Intent` as

```
Intent details = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
details.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
details.putExtra("data", "data");
context.startActivity(details);
```

In your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("data")){

  // call Enter data Fragment (via FragmentManager)

}
else{

  // call ListView Fragment (via FragmentManager)

}
```

Try this. This should work.

Comment: Worked like charm!!! Been working on that for some days now thanks. You made it very easy!